# What are .NET Core patterns for using middleware objects in downstream projects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Imagine the following project structure for a .NET Core Web project.

`Widget.UI` project (MVC) calls `Widget.Business` calls `Widget.Services` calls `Widget.Repository` project.

Let's say `Widget.Services` project wants to implement Distributed caching with [Memcached](https://github.com/cnblogs/EnyimMemcachedCore).

Is the pattern to add Memcached to middleware in Startup.ConfigureServices and .Configure, pass them into controller's constructor, then build constructors with Memcached all the way down the stack?

Or would it be better to better to `var cache = new MemcachedClient()` in the Widget.Services project?

Comment: Depends on what you're caching, but generally, you'll want to use DI to inject the reference to the distributed cache implementation in whatever layer you decide to use it. I would generally put it in the Repository, letting that component concern itself with whether to pull data from the cache or its configured repository.

Answer (score 1):

Memcached will be your infrastructure. So according to your design, service layer should define cashing abstraction and the implementation of this abstraction (using Memcached) could be (for example) in the `Widget.Infrastructure` project.

There may be good reason to cache in the repository layer too. But it depends on your needs. Then you should define cashing abstraction outside of the service layer.

Service configuration will be same as any other services (in the `Startup.ConfigureServices`) and you inject cashing infrastructure by constructor, where you need it.